# Range1.Value = Range2.Value not populating

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to move ranges of cells to one row, but different columns. The code worked fine when I was copy/pasting, but the sheet slowed down dramatically. This method seems to work faster, though the actual cells are not populating. Code below:

```
lastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i + 1, 4).Value Then                   '1st if
            Debug.Print Cells(i, 4).Value & "  " & Cells(i + 1, 4).Value

            If Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i + 2, 4).Value Then           '2nd if
                Debug.Print Cells(i, 4).Value & "    " & Cells(i + 2, 4).Value

                If Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i + 3, 4).Value Then       '3rd if
                    Debug.Print Cells(i, 4).Value & "    " & Cells(i + 3, 4).Value

                    If Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i + 4, 4).Value Then       '4th if
                        Debug.Print Cells(i, 4).Value & "    " & Cells(i + 4, 4).Value

                        If Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i + 5, 4).Value Then       '5th if

                            Debug.Print Cells(i, 4).Value & "    " & Cells(i + 5, 4).Value

                        Else '~~~~~>RANGE1.VALUE = RANGE2.VALUE BELOW

                                Cells(i + 4, 52).Value = 5
                                Range(Cells(i, 40), Cells(i, 50)).Value = Range(Cells(i + 4, 53), Cells(i + 4, 63)).Value
                                Range(Cells(i + 1, 40), Cells(i + 1, 50)).Value = Range(Cells(i + 4, 64), Cells(i + 4, 74)).Value
                                Range(Cells(i + 2, 40), Cells(i + 2, 50)).Value = Range(Cells(i + 4, 75), Cells(i + 4, 85)).Value
                                Range(Cells(i + 3, 40), Cells(i + 3, 50)).Value = Range(Cells(i + 4, 86), Cells(i + 4, 96)).Value

                                i = i + 4

                             End If
```

Comment: I'll ask the easy question before I look into your code in too much detail ... do you definitely have something in columns BA to CR?  And do you actually have situations where there are five consecutive rows with the same value in column D?

Comment: Do those 4 lines actually execute?

Comment: "I am attempting to move ranges of cells to one row, but different columns." Are you sure you have your assignment statements the right way around, i.e. are you trying to copy things from BA:BK of the 5th row to AN:AX of the 1st row, from BL:BV of the 5th row to AN:AX of the second row, etc (which is what you are doing), or are you trying to go the other way and move everything from the first 4 rows into the 5th row?

Comment: @YowE3K it is columns AN:AX, and yes I do. I do have situations like this, yes.

Comment: @YowE3K .... You were exactly right. I had it as RANGE1.VALUE = RANGE2.VALUE, not RANGE2.VALUE = RANGE1.value. Nailed it, amirite?!

Comment: @Gregory Yep - once you said you didn't have data in columns BA:CR, that it was in AN:AX, it became fairly obvious that you were just writing things back to front.  (I'm guessing you probably had lines like `Range(Cells(i, 40), Cells(i, 50)).Copy Range(Cells(i + 4, 53), Cells(i + 4, 63))` and you forgot that is written as `source.Copy destination` while an assignment is `destination = source`, and therefore edited the lines without remembering to switch the two sides.)

Comment: That's exactly right @YowE3K. Appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Basic the statement

```
a = b
```

modifies `a` so that it is given the value of `b`.  It doesn't change `b` to be the value of `a`.

---

Based on your comment that your data is in AN:AX, it therefore seems like you intended to use:

```
Range(Cells(i + 4, 53), Cells(i + 4, 63)).Value = Range(Cells(i + 0, 40), Cells(i + 0, 50)).Value
Range(Cells(i + 4, 64), Cells(i + 4, 74)).Value = Range(Cells(i + 1, 40), Cells(i + 1, 50)).Value
Range(Cells(i + 4, 75), Cells(i + 4, 85)).Value = Range(Cells(i + 2, 40), Cells(i + 2, 50)).Value
Range(Cells(i + 4, 86), Cells(i + 4, 96)).Value = Range(Cells(i + 3, 40), Cells(i + 3, 50)).Value
```